# namespaces and autoload - the right way

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I want to use Facebook's PHP SDK and want to implement __autoload with it and I'm having problems.

At first I thought that this will work:

```
function __autoload($class) {  
    if(file_exists(APPPATH."libraries/facebook/".$class.EXT)) {
        require_once(APPPATH."libraries/facebook/".$class.EXT);     
    }
}
```

The path is correct by the way.

Now I wanted to use:

```
$fb = new FacebookSession();
```

And it didn't work (unknown class), I then discovered this is FacebookSession.php:

```
namespace Facebook;
```

I'm not experienced with namespaces in PHP, but I tried this:

```
$fb = new Facebook\FacebookSession();
```

My autoloader stopped working, because now $class in __autoload is equal to "Facebook\FacebookSession"

How to handle this? I can't simply do explode or something similar on "\"  because, I believe, there can be more such elements, right? Or maybe it's enough to do explode and take the last element, which fill be the final class name to look for? It does work, but is this the right way?